# Query MySQL DB using preparedStatement.setDate

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc, prepared-statement

```
public java.util.List<Tag> getAlltagsByDate(String date ){

    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
    Connection conn = dataSource.createConnection();
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    Tag tags_Data = new Tag();
    String query = "select * from tag_data where tag_data_date  =  ?";
    try {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date nn  =df.parse(date);
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(date));
        resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

I am getting an error 
[image: Tomcat Error]

Can anyone help me with this,
I need to query mySQL db where date = input in html

[image]

Comment: It seems you have a MySQL syntax error exception. Check if the error message doesn't print out the SQL query that was actually executed.

Comment: I am using Simple Date datatype in mysql

Comment: Hi  xaviert, direct query if working fine in mysql:
select * from tag_data where tag_data_date =  '2015-12-11';

Comment: Can you suggest me a way to search row in db with 
date(tag_data_date)

Comment: AFAIK the SQL query looks OK. Did you validate the output of all the date parsing? (`java.sql.Date.valueOf(date).toString()`)

Comment: i am also doing 
**System.out.println(java.sql.Date.valueOf(date));**
and result is fine IT's **2015-12-11**

Comment: is it possible that you could post the full error (it cuts of at kind of an important part in your image post there) in particular the line that says "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.mysqlsyntaxerrorexception you have an error in yo...".    Maybe also include schema for your tag_data table.

Comment: There was something wrong in my servlet,
Now i am using String (data) for searching  as it's working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, skip the `Date` part; simply use the string.  Let's see the value of `(String date )`.

MySQL is happy if you can end up with `... tag_data_date = '2015-12-11'`.

If `String date` looks like '2015-12-11', then the conversion to `Date` is unnecessary.

Comment: Hi Rick , very simple solution as you suggested,

Answer (score 2):

I have presented a solution. As you have not mentioned much about your DB structure, so ,

Consider **test** as database name, and consisting of table **tag_data** having two columns id and tag_data_date as shown below.

```
 CREATE TABLE `tag_data` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_data_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Also consider data in table as

```
INSERT INTO `tag_data` (`id`, `tag_data_date`) VALUES
(1, '2015-12-20 00:00:00');
```

And your java class as below

```
public class JDBCPreparedStatementExample {

private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; //mysql driver class
private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"; //connectionstring
private static final String DB_USER = "root"; //mysql username
private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "root"; //mysql password

public static void main(String[] argv) throws ParseException {

    try {

        getDateForDate("2015-12-20"); //time passed as arguement

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

}
//Method to interact with DB and print data,this can be changed to return value of List<Key> as per your requirement
private static void getDateForDate(String date) throws SQLException, ParseException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    java.util.Date dateCal  =df.parse(date); // parse date in String to Date Object
    String updateTableSQL = "select * from tag_data where tag_data_date  =  ?";

    try {
//get DB connection
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
// Create preapared statement           
preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);

        preparedStatement.setDate(1, new Date(dateCal.getTime()));//convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date

        // execute update SQL stetement
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
         while (resultSet.next()) {
              // It is possible to get the columns via name
              // also possible to get the columns via the column number
              // which starts at 1
              // e.g. resultSet.getString(2);
              int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
              Date tag_data_date = resultSet.getDate("tag_data_date");
              System.out.println("Date: " + tag_data_date);
              System.out.println("Comment: " + id);
            }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }

    }

}

private static Connection getDBConnection() {

    Connection dbConnection = null;

    try {

        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    try {

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
        return dbConnection;

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    return dbConnection;

}

}
```

Comment: ,Thank you for solution, i am simple using String for date,and It's working fine now

Comment: IN DB you are storing date as string or as DATETIME datatype??

Comment: In database i am storing in DATETIME format,
and i am generating current time from Java.Util 
Now i am using Simple strings to search in db.
and it's working